# Drag and drop ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, file, upload, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to upload files with drag and drop functionality via ajax.  However, IE doesn't seem to support any type of drag and drop.  Is there any way for IE to accept file drag and drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ This plugin will handle an ajax file upload for you.

Answer (score 1):

IE10 is the first version of Internet Explorer to support file drag and drop.