# Passing file upload jquery and ajax

Tags: php

I am trying to upload file Jquery with ajax using php. If i passing Jquery data i not able to retrieve  the file upload data how can i pass jquery file upload data to ajax. Kindly some on help me how can upload file through jquery ajax with php..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531428/drag-and-drop-ajax-file-upload/8531445#8531445

Answer (score 0):

You cannot AJAX upload.

It's basically a fake AJAX to make it look like it is AJAX uploading.

In reality what happens is that the upload form is given a `target` of a nearby iframe. This makes it look like it is AJAX uploading when in reality it isn't.

The iframe is normally given a JS function within size of it that triggers a function in the parent windows which shows some kind of message say "Thank you for your upload".

Of course this is only really basic functionality and you'll need to Google search for more exampls, fortunately there are tonnes out there.